# How do I make Visual Studio always show the Source view instead of the Design view when hitting F7 from a codebehind page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ide, config

The <kbd>F7</kbd> key in **Visual Studio** - it allows the user to switch between the code for a designer element (e.g. a *Windows Form* or a *Web User Control*).

This works great in *Windows forms*: when I'm in the `.cs` file for a visual element (e.g. a *User Control*), it shows me the visual designer.

It doesn't work so great for me in **ASP.NET**:  When I'm in the markup (e.g. the Source view of the *Designer*), it takes me to the *CodeBehind*, which is exactly what I want. However, once in the *CodeBehind*, it takes me back to the *Design* view on the *Designer*, which is never what I want.

How do I make **Visual Studio** always show the *Source view* instead of the *Design view* when hitting <kbd>F7</kbd> from a *Codebehind* page?

Comment: Stumbled on this old question and noticed that the selected answer is wrong. Eduardo's answer is correct and works great. Suggest changing selected answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. *Tools* > *Options* > *Keyboard*
2. Search for **`View.ToggleDesigner`** in "**Show Commands Containing**".
3. Add new shortcut to **`Global`** with <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: In VS2015 it seems they renamed the Command to View.ToggleDesigner

Comment: I wish I'd have known about this eight years ago! Brilliant tip.

Comment: Confusing naming, but does exactly what we want!

Answer (score 16):

To Set That Open Options From Tools in Visual Studio:

1. Tools > Options > HTML Designer (Left Navigation)
2. Then make sure "Enable HTML designer" is Checked
3. Then select "Source View" from "Start pages in".

[image: This picture is taken from Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: This picture is taken from **VS2010**.

Regarding working F7, It works when a Page is opening, either by double click in solution explorer or press F7 from Code Behind File. If the file is already opened it will retain its state, either of "Source View", "Design View" or "Split View"

Comment: In VS2015 menu option was renamed: Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work in ASP.NET but there is a setting under options -> HTML Designer to start pages in Source view, Design view or split view.  Might want to try that.

Comment: It looks like what you've described is the default option, so that's not going to work.  It makes the Source view appear if you double-click the file, but I don't know why the behavior is not consistent for F7.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click any .html/.htm file in Solution Explorer and select **Open With…**

Now select **HTML (Web Forms) Editor**,click **Set as Default** and then hit OK.

All files with the same extension will now always open in the Web Forms editor and you get both Design- and Split view.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 use the "Source View" option under "Web Forms Designer"

[image: Visual Studio 2022 options dialog box]